# Is there a way to authenticate as a Firebase Auth user with the Firestore python SDK?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have access to both the `id_token` and `refresh_token` of a user authenticated with Firebase. Can I somehow use the firestore package in python on behalf of that user? Or does it only use service accounts?

Answer (score 2):

The Firestore backend SDKs provided by Google Cloud SDKs don't know how to work with Firebase Auth users.  They only work with service accounts.  You must be using one of the web or mobile SDKs to work with Firebase Auth users, and they will do so automatically, only for the currently signed in user.

If you want to auth as a user outside of web or mobile apps, you can use the REST API as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization).